# RTDs: Resistive Divider or Wheatstone bridge

Tags: voltage-divider, wheatstone-bridge, rtd

I've inherited a PCB design in which the circuit for reading a 1k 2-wire RTD sensor is a simple resistive divider. The R_rtd is the pulldown part of the divider. The voltage of the divider is read into a 16bit ADC where it is sampling around 500Hz+. We're only interested in a 1Hz sample rate so the samples are averaged.

The range in which we're concerned for reading temperatures is only around room temp to roughly a "hot summer day." This stays well within the linear range of the RTD. The leads for the RTD are relatively short, about 1 ft. This shorter range seems negligible unless we're looking for >0.1 degrees of accuracy.

I've always used a Wheatstone, but am not sure if I need to redesign the PCB.

What kind of additional accuracy would a Wheatstone provide given our ranges and sample rate of interest?

Comment: I think the wheatstone is supposed to cancel the drift of its own resistors.

Comment: IMO Wheatstones are mainly useful if you want to detect really small relative changes such as 1e-4 and below. depending on the equipment you can do without bridges even at relative changes of 1e-8 and below.. You need an accurac of perhaps 1e-3, so IMO a wheatstone bridge is needless overkill. A wheatstone bridge with cheap resistors can be more hassle than its worth.

Comment: Thank you! I remember doing calculations in my labs in school, but 
a) wasn't sure if they're critical for most applications in the real world and 
b) if they are used, how critical they are to the accuracy. 
Thank you for your input.